# Vuetify Treeview - set default selected when option items are retrieved asynchronously

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js, vuejs3

I have a Vuetify TreeView component used across the app for which I need to be able to pass in a list of selected values alongside the option list.

The option list is retrieved using an http call. The problem is that the vuetify tree view component doesn't show the selected items when the option item list is not initialized before the selected list

See this codepen - https://codepen.io/amaieras/pen/eYVZJJq?editors=101

While if I initialize the items directly in the data, the default selected items appear as selected in the tree component - https://codepen.io/amaieras/pen/bGLpEBx?editors=101

```
<v-treeview
   ref="tree"
    v-model="selectedTerms"
    :class="contentClass"
    :filter="filter"
    :indeterminate-icon="'far fa-minus-square'"
    :items="applicabilityTagsValues"
    :on-icon="'ph-square-logo-fill'"
    :open.sync="expanded"
    :search="searchValue"
    class="dropdown-treeview"
    selectable
    selected-color="neutral lighten-4"
    @input="emit('input', $event)"
    >
    </v-treeview>


store
   .dispatch('businessContextRequirements/getApplicabilityTagsFilters',
      filtersValuesPayload.value
     ).then((resp) => { applicabilityTagsValues.value = resp })
```

I can use a force mechanism to rerender the treeview component, but I am wondering if there is another way of making the component to render the selected nodes using vue's reactivity?

Using force mechanism

```
    <v-treeview
            ref="tree"
            :key="dropdownKey"
            v-model="selectedTerms"
            :class="contentClass"
            :filter="filter"
            :indeterminate-icon="'far fa-minus-square'"
            :items="applicabilityTagsValues"
            :on-icon="'ph-square-logo-fill'"
            :open.sync="expanded"
            :search="searchValue"
            class="dropdown-treeview"
            selectable
            selected-color="neutral lighten-4"
            @input="emit('input', $event)"
            >
            </v-treeview>
        
        
    setup() {
    const dropdownKey = 0     
store.dispatch('businessContextRequirements/getApplicabilityTagsFilters',
              filtersValuesPayload.value
             ).then((resp) => { 
       dropdownKey++;
       applicabilityTagsValues.value = resp 
    })
    return {
      dropdownKey,
      applicabilityTagsValues
      }
    }
```